# PouchDB throwing "possible EventEmitter memory leak detected" warnings

Tags: pouchdb

I'm building an application using PouchDB and have come across this error. I've just started using Pouch and the community has been great with helping me get a better understand and answering my questions.

The application loads a document from PouchDB and then saves it periodically. after about 6 or 7 saves I get the following error in the console.

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. 
Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.

console.trace()
  87.EventEmitter.addListener @ pouchdb.js:11140setUpEventEmitter @ pouchdb.js:
  1044781.PouchDB.defaults @ pouchdb.js:
  10583(anonymous function) @ eval.js:10
  1../postmessagerpc.js @ eval.js:52
  s @ eval.js:1e @ eval.js:1
  (anonymous function) @ eval.js:1
```

Now, taking a look at http://pouchdb.com/errors.html#event_emitter_limit I see the following callout:

> This could indicate a memory leak in your code. Check to make sure that you are calling cancel() on any changes(), replicate(), or sync() handlers, if you are constantly starting and stopping those events.

I'm retrieving the record with the following code in my service:

```
obj.get = function (uuid) {
  return localDB.get(uuid).then(function (response) {
    //$log.info(response);
    return response;
  });
};
```

And then when a button is clicked I save the document using the following in my service:

```
obj.save = function (doc) {
  return localDB.put(doc).then(function (response) {
    return response;
  }).catch(function (err) {
    $log.error(err);
    return false;
  });
};
```

I don't have a good enough understanding of this to tell exactly why it is happening. According to the documentation I would think that this would only be present on `.on()`, `'.changes()`, `.sync()` or `.replicate()`.

Is it likely that I have a memory leak? Why would saving the document cause the emitters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the "pouchDB inspector" chrome plugin it is possible that is causing this problem. I have just opened an issue on that repository describing it. It does not appear to actually be a memory leak.

https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-fauxton-chrome-extension/issues/12

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `PouchDB.defaults()` multiple times? That's where that `setUpEventEmitter()` line is getting called: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/blob/f7280a792ff73a76cd7145166326dd0feb0bde78/lib/setup.js#L126

Comment: Thanks. I'm only doing gets and puts. Nothing crazy going on but now that you bring this up, I am also using angular-pouch so perhaps that is the culprit. its a pretty simple code (only 89 lines) but I do see `.on()` references.  https://github.com/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb/blob/master/angular-pouchdb.js